# C: execvp() and command line arguments

Tags: c, execvp

So I'm writing a program where the *arguments are as follows*:

```
program start emacs file.c
```

or even

```
program wait
```

In essence, the first argument (argv[0]) is the program name, followed by user inputs.

Inside my code, I invoke execvp. Thing is, I'm not entirely sure I'm invoking the right arguments.

```
if (pid == 0) { 
                    execvp(argv[1], argv); //Line of interest
                    exit(1);
                    }
```

are argv[1] and argv the correct arguments to pass for the functionality described above? I looked at the man page and they make sense but might not be correct for this case.
Thank you!

Comment: You'll note from the answers the common theme: `execvp(cmds[n], &cmds[n]);` or the equivalent.  That is, you pass the nth element of the array of arguments as the first argument to `execvp()`, and you pass the address of the nth element of the array of arguments as the second argument -- in your specific case, `execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);`.  Clearly, you aren't technically obliged to do this (the arguments are independent), but you need a very good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main, argv will be like this in the first example:

```
argv[0] = "program";
argv[1] = "start";
argv[2] = "emacs";
argv[3] = "file.c";
argv[4] = NULL;
```

In execv you want to execute the program "start" with args "emacs file.c", right?. Then the first parameter should be argv[1] - "start" and the second one an array with this strings: {"start", "emacs", "file.c", NULL}. If you use argv, you include the "program" string in argv[0].

You can create a new array and copy these parameters or use the address of argv[1] like this:

```
execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]); //Line of interest
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that might be an issue is that `argv[0]` in `argv` passed to `execvp` won't match `argv[1]` (the first argument). Otherwise, it looks okay.

Imagine calling `program cat file.txt`. In your program, argv will be `{"program", "cat", "file.txt", NULL}`. Then, in cat, even though the binary called will be cat, argv will still be `{"program", "cat", "file.txt", NULL}`.

Since `cat` tries to open and read each argument as a file, the first file it'll try to open is `cat` (`argv[1]`), which isn't the desired behavior.

The simple solution is to use `execvp(argv[1], argv+1)` - this essentially shifts the argument array to the left by one element.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to take a specific action based on the second command-line argument (`argv[1]`). If the second argument is 'start', your program should start the executable named `argv[2]` with the arguments provided thereafter (right?). In this case, you should provide `execvp` with the executable name (`argv[2]`) [1] and a list of arguments, which by convention starts with the name of the executable (`argv[2]`).

`execvp(argv[2], &argv[2])` would implement what we have described in the last paragraph (assuming this is what you intended to do).

[1] `execvp` expects 2 arguments as you know. The first is a filename; if the specified filename does not contain a slash character (/), `execvp` will do a lookup in the PATH environment variable  (which contains a list of directories where executable files reside) to find the executable's fully-qualified name. The second argument is a list of command-line arguments that will be available to the program when it starts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, according to the second example, that `argv[1]` is the intended target executable.